# How to get "source" from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to build a custom Facebook page feed into my website. When the posts on the Facebook page have only images it works great, but when they have videos we've got a problem. What I would like to happen is a mini version of the video to be place as it was an image itself. However I'm a newbie to the graph api, because of that I don't know how to grab the "source" element of the posts that have video on them.

Here is how the JSON objetc looks like:

```
{
   "name": "Patrick Oliveira",
   "picture": {
      "data": {
         "is_silhouette": false,
         "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xft1/v/t1.0-1/c13.0.50.50/p50x50/11694800_709940652467661_5760283552162746065_n.jpg?oh=8ce289debf38df76b1a8ad72e9e32950&oe=5641D882&__gda__=1447414822_01484acd6dcdb29c62a7278a140bb592"
      }
   },
   "posts": {
      "data": [
         {
            "full_picture": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xft1/v/t1.0-9/p417x417/11873451_734632043331855_4522184841179328970_n.jpg?oh=67bd84af22a94bc59a2996ff8fa0a8d8&oe=563F7BE8&__gda__=1447502842_a29144ab596e29d3d92d2239d376adc9",
            "message": "Lan\u00e7ado em fevereiro de 1990, o Photoshop completa 25 anos como o programa de edi\u00e7\u00e3o de imagens mais famoso do mundo. Parab\u00e9ns Adobe!",
            "created_time": "2015-08-14T20:52:08+0000",
            "id": "213578595437205_734632043331855"
         },
         {
            "full_picture": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xft1/v/t1.0-9/q81/s720x720/11415380_700706213391105_871834721491614634_n.jpg?oh=8672f7ae4931323baaf012e5f57a6079&oe=567F5D35",
            "message": "\"Agora eu sei de que \u00e9 feito aquele ch\u00e3o\".\n-- cliente",
            "created_time": "2015-07-04T20:05:01+0000",
            "id": "213578595437205_700706213391105"
         },
         {
            "full_picture": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpt1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/11406889_700700410058352_5592320885219405365_n.jpg?oh=acedee420f8e4944201c714e30f70627&oe=5679534C&__gda__=1451225194_477268223eedc2217b2ae1dcdd345399",
            "message": "Levante que hoje \u00e9 Sexta!",
            "created_time": "2015-07-03T09:27:01+0000",
            "id": "213578595437205_700700410058352"
         },
         {
            "full_picture": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBxQzu6zRD6fM_d&w=720&h=720&url=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fi.ytimg.com\u00252Fvi\u00252F2K9eMZyD5jc\u00252Fmaxresdefault.jpg&cfs=1",
            "message": "Ferramenta poderosa pra quem trabalha com fotos de arquitetura, o Adaptive Wide Angle pode ser um poderoso aliado!\nhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2K9eMZyD5jc",
            "created_time": "2015-07-02T18:25:01+0000",
            "source": "http://www.youtube.com/v/2K9eMZyD5jc?version=3&autohide=1&autoplay=1",
            "id": "213578595437205_700700186725041"
         },
         {
            "full_picture": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xft1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/541646_700699430058450_5858057325981612930_n.jpg?oh=24a5d3e03cf1f782262e0b72d04831b4&oe=567999FA&__gda__=1451117341_93c352ddfa2804fa4047d84ab94978d9",
            "message": "Come\u00e7ando o m\u00eas de Julho com o p\u00e9...",
            "created_time": "2015-07-01T10:23:00+0000",
            "id": "213578595437205_700699430058450"
         }
      ],
      "paging": {
         "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/213578595437205/posts?limit=5&fields=full_picture,message,created_time,source&since=1439585528&access_token=1641569939420394|NyfBDunYwpFoZrtAoCSfqTV2-uU&__paging_token=enc_AdDQS8eEeKGQ3tvUJJxS1kyUXRwabHz2C1GZA0QZCufpZCHklYUI76WLCrigOB3IT1yxUtsCvx60ZA2haPnZA2Xoc2BOvPOLkM9eZBrbbrV1A87hVgIgZDZD&__previous=1",
         "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/213578595437205/posts?limit=5&fields=full_picture,message,created_time,source&access_token=1641569939420394|NyfBDunYwpFoZrtAoCSfqTV2-uU&until=1435746180&__paging_token=enc_AdAVBcOniyc1nbopw3Gr3CkmZB1pUDYBmZBghDmQXLunZBbvcuO1xttx6vpnkZBskAawu1sdcfh6qZCrU3sZA5MzZAkRQMT2VALYxOkCJOQZCm38ebDd2wZDZD"
      }
   },
   "id": "213578595437205"
}
```

The fourth post is a video post, so I thought maybe I could generate a smaller video feed if I could grab that video source there.

Here is what I've been trying to do:

```
$.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/"+$page_id+"/?fields=name,picture,posts{full_picture,message,created_time}&access_token="+$access_token, function(fb) {
        fb.posts.data[3].source;
    });
```

However, the only thing I get from that is "undefined". If I do `fb.posts.data[3].message` or `fb.posts.data[3].created_time` or any of the other options it works, just for source that it returns "undefined". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'll want to inspect the object to make sure you're not misspelling it.

Comment: are you sure it object look like it???

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was missing the source in the url request. Sorry to bother you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong, so stupid. The request URL was missing the source element. So with this it works:

```
$.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/"+$page_id+"/?fields=name,picture,posts{full_picture,message,created_time,source}&access_token="+$access_token, function(fb) {
        fb.posts.data[3].source;
    });
```

I'm sorry for the mistake, it was my bad.